# ios - memory warning and crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, warnings

in my app i have a UIWebView and in that web view  i am loading some text and images. I am getting those datas by parsing from an rss feed. When large datas get loaded my app get crashed saying that memory warning. How to avoid this memory warning issues in my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but there's only one real answer to this: use less memory.

When you get the memory warning you should clear out any caches or temporary data that can be recalculated. As you've found, if you don't do that iOS will kill your app.